# Twig add asset image with special characters

Tags: image, symfony, twig, assets

I'm trying to add images in a twig with different sizes

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji.jpg') }}" srcset="{{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji.jpg') }} 1x, {{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji@2x.jpg') }} 2x" alt="">
```

and this return an error

> Unexpected character "@".

How can I make to add @ inside an asset?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution replacing @ for %40 like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji.jpg') }}" srcset="{{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji.jpg') }} 1x, {{ asset('img/front/portfolio/fuji%402x.jpg') }} 2x" alt="">
```

Hope it helps someone!